# Getting error while running play framework in production mode

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am getting an error when running for production from dist, But its working in the same system with development mode and same DB.

```
sudo ./sampleapp -Dhttp.port=9010  -J-Xms128M -J-Xmx512m -J-server
```

> Password:
>       [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
>       [error] c.z.h.p.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
>       com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'arisetec_ftalent'
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943)
>       [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
>       [error] c.z.h.p.HikariPool - HikariPool-2 - Exception during pool initialization.
>       com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'arisetec_ftalent'
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943)
>       Oops, cannot start the server.
>       Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
>         at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:155)
>         at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:984)
>         at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$connect$1(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
>         at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$connect$1$adapted(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
>         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
>         at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
>         at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:86)
>         at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:75)
>         at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:56)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:54)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:62)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:987)
>         at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
>         at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies$$FastClassByGuice$$2a7177aa.invoke()
>         at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:54)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:89)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:223)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.injectAll(Initializer.java:132)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:174)
>         at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
>         at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
>         at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
>         at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:185)
>         at play.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceBuilder.java:221)
>         at play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.java:156)
>         at modules.LogSdtErrLoader.load(LogSdtErrLoader.java:29)
>         at play.api.ApplicationLoader$JavaApplicationLoaderAdapter$1.load(ApplicationLoader.scala:87)
>         at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:50)
>         at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:25)
>         at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
>       Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Failed to initialize pool: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database
>   'arisetec_ftalent']
>         at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:155)
>         at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:984)
>         at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:63)
>         at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
>         at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
>         at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
>         at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
>         at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
>         at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$connect$1(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
>         ... 52 more
>       Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed
>   to initialize pool: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database
>   'arisetec_ftalent'
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:543)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:535)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:111)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:72)
>         at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.$anonfun$create$1(HikariCPModule.scala:51)
>         at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
>         at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:47)
>         ... 58 more
>       Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access
>   denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'arisetec_ftalent'
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4113)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1308)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:112)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:443)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:514)
>         ... 63 more

Comment: Your database user has no access to the database `arisetec_ftalent `

Comment: But i can able to access from sbt run or dev mode with out any issue

Comment: Hmm.. The error seems to be a little be too long... Is there any ways to shorten it(*well I don't how, but just a suggestion*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database configuration in for the production environment is missing the username of the database user. Take a closer look at the error message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'arisetec_ftalent'

Its says

> Access denied for user **''**@'localhost'

The username is empty. Please check your configuration.